# Resolution of Page Being Called In IFrame

Tags: iframe

Is there a way to adjust this?  So basically the resolution of the page can be based on the dimensions you give the iFrame?

For example, if I said :

```
<iframe src="http://www.abigpage.com" height="500" width="500"></iframe>
```

And "www.abigpage.com" had content that was 1000x1000, could you adjust it so it showed up as 50% of its original size to fit the iFrame?  I suppose I could set the called page's CSS properties to percentages and that may work, but is there a way to specify this no matter what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only work for IE :(

```
yourIframe {
    zoom:50%;
}
```

If it's on the same domain you can have a look here:
http://sonspring.com/journal/jquery-iframe-sizing

Else: due to the security limitation, no you can't edit/resize the content of the iFrame.

Comment: yea I was surprised to find almost nothing on this subject.  Ah well, thanks!